# How to get client IP address in Vapor 3.0?

Tags: swift, vapor

Although there used to be some methods to get client IP address (e.g. `req.peerHostname` ), I cannot figure out how to get it in Vapor 3.0.

Could anyone please let me know how to get client IP address in Vapor 3.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to the Vapor community, I have got an answer.

You can use `req.http.remotePeer.hostname` for Vapor 3.0 project.

Comment: Hello, do you know how to do this with for Vapor 4?

Comment: This isn't working on Vapor 4

Answer (score 1):

Hi hope this helps for **Vapor 4** use this

```
func getIp(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<String> {
        print(req.headers.forwarded.first!.for)
        return req.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture("\(req.headers.forwarded.first!.for ?? "Not found")")
 }
```

works fine for me not the best solution I guess but it works :)

Comment: This answer only works if the HTTP header "forwarded" is set. Today, most proxies will use the "x-forwarded-for" header. If there is no proxy, then this answer will fail.

Answer (score 1):

For **Vapor 4** use this

```
req.remoteAddress?.ipAddress
```

Comment: This answer does not work if the swift server is running behind a proxy (load balancer).

Answer (score 1):

Vapor 4 includes a method of determining the remote peer address that supports setups with and without a proxy (load balancer).

Use `req.peerAddress`

[Source code comments](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/main/Sources/Vapor/Request/Request.swift#L36)

> We try to determine true peer address if load balacer or reversed
> proxy provided info in headers Priority of getting value from headers
> is as following:
>
> 1. try the "Forwarded" header (e.g. for=192.0.2.60; proto=http; by=203.0.113.43)
> 2. try the "X-Forwarded-For" header (e.g. client_IP, proxy1_IP, proxy2_IP)
> 3. fallback to the socket's remote address provided by SwiftNIO ( e.g. 192.0.2.60:62934)
>
> in 1. and 2. will use port 80 as default port, and  3. will have port number provided by NIO if any

[Request.swift source code](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/main/Sources/Vapor/Request/Request.swift#L44)

```
public var peerAddress: SocketAddress? {
    if let clientAddress = headers.forwarded.first?.for {
        return try? SocketAddress.init(ipAddress: clientAddress, port: 80)
    }

    if let xForwardedFor = headers.first(name: .xForwardedFor) {
        return try? SocketAddress.init(ipAddress: xForwardedFor, port: 80)
    }

    return self.remoteAddress
}
```